# Wiring a 7705 5V Regultaor

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, transformer, 5v, step-down

I went to the store the other day to pick up a 7805 voltage regulator. (5V DC) However, the store was out and so I bought a 'TL7705ACP' IC 5V DC regulator. I am wondering how to wire it up, to step down 12V DC to 5V DC for a project of mine.

How can I wire the 7705 to achieve this goal in the most simple manner?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it only requires information in the datasheet.

Comment: Read the datasheet.  Closing because we are not here to read it for you, and -1 because that really should have been obvious.

Comment: The first thing I did was study the data sheet, but I do not fully understand it. My project is designed to help me learn, and that is what I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

Bad news: you can't, because it's not a voltage regulator.

[The TL7705A is a "supply-voltage supervisor".](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl7705a.pdf) It's designed to generate power-on reset signals. You can read the datasheet for details, but it's not what you want -- take it back, if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because the part you bought is not a regulator at all- it is a supply voltage supervisor.